# can't find nvidia 3D settings

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 21.10, nvidia-geforce

The question explains it all, when I enter nvidia control center (Nvidia X Server Settings) I can't find 3D settings anywhere. Am I searching wrong? or are there not any.

It can't be my pc, because when I used windows I could find those settings without a problem.

OS version 21.10

GPU GeForce GTX 750 Ti

Comment: Hello. It would help if you said the model of the NVIDIA card.

Comment: it's GeForce GTX 750 Ti

Comment: Please use edit and add that to the question.

Comment: You appear to running a quite old card. All the web sites say the same only certified up to Windows 8. What can a GTX 750 Ti run?
The GTX 750 Ti is slightly better than the GT 1030 and RX 550, and the i5–3470 quad-core is very acceptable. If you turn off anti-aliasing and play AAA games on low, you should manage to play most of them at 1080p. Overwatch and Fortnite should do pretty well. GTA is an NVIDIA title and should be quite good as well. There is no mention of 3D support in any site I can find. So I think it is correct to not have that option.

Comment: As I said when I still had windows I could easily find them, there was a section called 3D settings or something like that.

It looked something like this: https://www.buyersguidex.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Nvidia-best-3d-settings-2-1024x793.png

Comment: Does not mean that the Ubuntu driver has this feature for this very old card.